# Adjoint of an operator on scaled Euclidean spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

For $N\in \mathbb N$, equip $\mathbb C^N$ with the inner product $\langle\mathbf x,\mathbf y\rangle_N := N^{-1}\sum_i \overline x_i y_i$. Let $A$ be an $N\times M$ complex matrix. As an linear operator from $\mathbb C^M$ to $\mathbb C^N$, what is the adjoint of $A$?

Now for $\mathbf x\in \mathbb C^M$ and $\mathbf y \in \mathbb C^N$, we have
$$
\langle A \mathbf x, y\rangle_N 
= N^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^M \overline A_{ij} \overline{\mathbf x}_j \mathbf  y_i 
= N^{-1} \sum_j \overline{\mathbf x}_j (A^*\mathbf y)_j = MN^{-1} \langle\mathbf x, A^* \mathbf y\rangle_M,
$$
suggesting that the adjoint of $A$ as an operator is not the Hermitian transpose. I'm not sure how to interpret this.

I'm guessing that the matrix $A$ is not a representation of the linear transform with respect to an orthonormal basis?

Comment: How about $MN^{-1} A^*$ ?

Comment: Yeah that would obviously fit the definition of the adjoint. How do I interpret the fact that it is different from the Hermitian transpose?

Comment: The Hermitian transpose is the adjoint for the natural inner product and you are not considering the inner product.

Comment: I see. So the operator norm of $A$ and $A^*$ will be different be exactly a factor of $MN^{-1}$ as well?

Comment: You're going to expect some square roots, since norms are square roots of inner products.